# Selected Edittext not visible with keyboard presence

Tags: android, android-edittext, scrollview, android-softkeyboard, adjustpan

1. Signup UI without keyboard
2. I tried to enter email, then the keyboard presents and the email field is not visible

   Here is my signup layout file:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <ScrollView 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
     android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
     android:fillViewport="true"
     android:isScrollContainer="true">

       <RelativeLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
   android:orientation="vertical">


   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_centerInParent="true"
       android:orientation="vertical">


       <EditText
           android:id="@+id/sign_up_email_input"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
           android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
           android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
           android:background="@drawable/capsule_shape"
           android:drawableLeft="@drawable/email_image"
           android:drawablePadding="10dp"
           android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
           android:hint="@string/input_mail"
           android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
           android:paddingLeft="20dp"
           android:textSize="16sp" />            

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/signup_button"
           android:layout_width="120dp"
           android:layout_height="40dp"
           android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
           android:background="@drawable/capsule_button"
           android:text="@string/btn_sign_text"
           android:textAllCaps="false"
           android:textColor="@color/white" />

   </LinearLayout>

       </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>
   ```

I have used the above layout xml file to design a Signup UI.  And, I am getting `email field not visible` issues while the keyboard is present. Please help me fix this issue.

Comment: What are you using `adjustpan` or adjustresize` ?

Comment: @Heisen I have used  adjustresize in Android manifest file